# Recursion - how many options to climb the building with n floors

Tags: java, recursion

Well I have "spiderman" which climbs the building which has n floors.
How many options does he have to get to the n'th floor if he knows to climb everytime one floor or two floors.

Here is what I did so far: (No arrays, no For loops, keep it simple)

```
public static int spiderman(int n,int i,int sum){
    if ( n == 0 )    return 0;
    if ( n < i) return 0;
    if ( n == i) return 1;
    sum += i;
    return spiderman(n,i + 1,sum) + spiderman(n,i + 2,sum);
}


  public static void main( String [] args ){
        System.out.println(spiderman(4,0,0)); //Should return 5
    }
```

Output:`spiderman(4)` returns 5. --Solved!

Comment: Please provide a runnable example. Your function has 3 arguments. You've only provided 1... Add in a `main()` that calls `spiderman(,,)` and prints the result.

Comment: What you mean with the statment: 'how many options does he have to get to the n-th floor?' You mean how many possible combinations of 1-floor-climb and 2-floor-climb?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Click edit on the post and put the additional code in. At lease edit `spiderman(5)` to `spiderman(5,0,0)`.

Comment: Solved. thanks to @Ivo

Comment: i added some extra info to my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your `if ( n > i) return 0;` should be `if ( n < i) return 0;`, reverse the sign.

also, you `sum` variable does not seem necessary. It doesn't do anything and has no influence on the result of your function

Bonus:

The question you need to answer is actually similar to the Fibonacci sequence. Which means you will see the following pattern:
spiderman(n, 0, 0) == spiderman(n - 1, 0, 0) + spiderman(n - 2, 0, 0).
Because the number of ways to get to a floor is equal to the number of ways he can get to the floor below + 2 floors below, becuase those are the floors from which he can reach his goal.

Therefore this is an alternative solution to your problem

```
public static int spiderman(int n){
    if (n < 3) return n;
    return spiderman(n - 1) + spiderman(n -2);
}
```